# How to Write Response Assertion Using Groovy in JMeter

Tags: http, groovy, jmeter

I want to write a code for Response assertion using groovy for one of the Request Giving Response data like this

```
{
"value":"200"
"value_description":"pass"
"value_code":"pass"
"data_encode":"uyt-09-0nbv"
}
```

after google Search i am getting only with Response Assertion  SOAP-UI tools and i also checked with Blaze meter blog i am not understating about what they are saying. simple way i want demonstrate that.write code for Response Data  Assert value for 200 is this possible. please help me to this stuff

Comment: Why you need to use groovy? You have JSON Extractor you can use

Comment: Because my Requriment deals with groovy script

Answer (score 2):

The relevant Groovy code to check whether `value` attribute in the response equals `200` would be something like:

```
def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData())

def value = json.value

if (value != '200') {
    AssertionResult.setFailure(true)
    AssertionResult.setFauilreMessage('Expected 200, but got ' + value)
}
```

1. Add [JSR223 Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) as a child of the request which returns the aforementioned JSON (it is not valid JSON by the way)
2. Put the above code into "Script" area (make sure you tick `Cache compiled script if available` box and choose `groovy` from the "Language" dropdown)

More information:

- [Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Scripting JMeter Assertions in Groovy - A Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

You can add 4 [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor)s, each with different Path Expressions:

`$.value`, `$.value_description`, `$.value_code`, `$.data_encode`

It will assert that JSON parameter returned.

You can add [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor)s to check each variable you got using Apply to `JMeter Variable`.